# In Mirth (nextgen-connect) how do I configure the HTTP URL of an HTTP Listener

Tags: kubernetes, httplistener, mirth

The manual says this about the HTTP URL value of an http listener:

"Displays the generated HTTP URL for the HTTP Listener. This is not an actual
configurable setting, but is instead displayed for copy/paste convenience. Note
that the host in the URL will be the same as the host you used to connect to
the Administrator. The actual host that connecting clients use may be different
due to differing networking environments."

When I have used the feature in the past its value has always begun "*http://localhost:*" which would be great except this time it is auto-generating " *http://'domainName':${Incoming_Pathology_Source_Port}/${Incoming_Pathology_Source_BaseContextPath}/*"

For the first time, we are deploying Mirth inside a Kubernetes cluster, 'a different working environment'.  (nginx accepts https and we want it pass the messages on as http to Mirth).

Is there any way I can take control of the URL or must I change the configuration of the cluster in some way.

All help/suggestions welcome.

Comment: Do you have a virtual IP address that you are using for your cluster?